# Problem with taking a screenshot of a URL with browsershot

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, browsershot

I've tested [browsershot](https://github.com/spatie/browsershot) locally (*Windows 10 **Pro***, *XAMPP*, *nodejs* **v14.17.6**), but I've faced a problem that I can't solve. I'm getting the following error:

```
The command "C:/node/nodejs/node.exe ^"C:^\xampp^\htdocs^\website^\vendor^\spatie^\browsershot^\src/../bin/browser.js^" ^"^{^\^"url^\^":^\^"http:^\/^\/example.com^\^",^\^"action^\^":^\^"screenshot^\^",^\^"options^\^":^{^\^"type^\^":^\^"png^\^",^\^"path^\^":^\^"C:^\^\xampp^\^\htdocs^\^\website^\^\storage^\^\app^\/browsershot^\/example.com.jpg^\^",^\^"args^\^":^[^],^\^"viewport^\^":^{^\^"width^\^":800,^\^"height^\^":600^}^}^}^"" failed. 
Exit Code: 1(General error) 
Working directory: C:\xampp\htdocs\website\public 
Output: 
================ Error Output: ================ 
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdtemp 'undefined\temp\puppeteer_dev_chrome_profile-XXXXXX'] { errno: -4058, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'mkdtemp', path: 'undefined\\temp\\puppeteer_dev_chrome_profile-XXXXXX' }
```

I'm so confused. Tried almost everything that people were saying in the forums that might solve the problem - but nothing worked. Can you help me up? Is the problem coming from the nodejs version? Where is the problem coming from?

The project is on **Laravel 8**.